# How to use multiple caches on GitLab-CI?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have three jobs:

- **job a**: cache things in directory **a/**
- **job b**: needs things from directory **a/** and cache things in directory **b/**
- **job c**: needs things from both directories

According to the [GitLab CI caching documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#use-multiple-caches), we can have a maximum of 4 caches, so I tried this:

```yaml
a:
    cache:
        key:
            files:
                - a.txt
        paths:
            - a/
        policy: pull-push
    script:
        - mkdir a/
        - echo "A" > a/a.txt

b:
    needs: [a]
    cache:
        -   key:
                files:
                    - b.txt
            paths:
                - b/
            policy: pull-push
        -   key:
                files:
                    - a.txt
            paths:
                - a/
            policy: pull
    script:
        - mkdir b/
        - echo "B" > b/b.txt
        - cat a/a.txt >> b/b.txt

c:
    needs: [b]
    cache:
        -   key:
                files:
                    - b.txt
            paths:
                - b/
            policy: pull
        -   key:
                files:
                    - a.txt
            paths:
                - a/
            policy: pull
    script:
        - cat a/*.txt
        - cat b/*.txt
```

It doesn't work because when **job b** is finished, only the **b/** directory is in the cache.

Indeed, on the server there is only one **archive.zip** file which contains only the directory **b/**. So, what's the aim of multiple caches if only the last **pull** is left? I thought the cache policy will get specified paths from the archive when **pulling** and add specified paths when **pushing**, not replace all the content.

The real directories are **vendor/** from **composer** for **job A** and **node_modules/** from **yarn** for **job B**, that's why I want to split them in order to only pull what I need without pushing to save time, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I misunderstand the aim of `key.files`. I solved my problem by simply using different key names for my caches.

```yaml
.a-cache: &a-cache
    key: a-cache-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
        - a/
    policy: pull

.b-cache: &b-cache
    key: b-cache-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
        - b/
    policy: pull

a:
    cache:
        - <<: *a-cache
          policy: pull-push
    script:
        - mkdir a/
        - echo "A" > a/a.txt

b:
    needs: [a]
    cache:
        - <<: *a-cache
        - <<: *b-cache
          policy: pull-push
    script:
        - mkdir b/
        - echo "B" > b/b.txt
        - cat a/a.txt >> b/b.txt

c:
    needs: [b]
    cache:
        - <<: *a-cache
        - <<: *b-cache
    script:
        - cat a/*.txt
        - cat b/*.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain where to get details about the command substiution you are using?
.a-cache: &cache seems pretty handy if you need the cache in multiple jobs, but I didn´t know this is possible.

Comment: @Crztean it's pure YAML anchor system: define an anchor with "&anchor-name" then refer to it as many time as needed with "*anchor-name"